# Link de histórico de edições dá erro

Tags: suporte, bug, status-pronto, histórico-de-revisões

Estou tentando visualizar o histórico [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276762/132).

O link para o histórico é [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/276762/revisions).

Ao acessar esse link, eis o resultado:

[image: workin on ur problemz]

Nas outras questões que testei, o link do histórico funciona normalmente.

Alguém consegue reproduzir esse erro nessa pergunta? Ou ele só acontece comigo? Por que isso acontece?

---

## English version

**Title: Edit history link throws error**

I'm trying to see the edit history for [this question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276762/132).

The link to the history is [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/276762/revisions).

When trying to access that link, I get this:

[image: workin on ur problemz]

In other questions that I tested in, the edit history link works fine.

Can someone reproduce the error in this question? Or is it only happening with me? Why is it happening?

Comment: Aqui deu erro também, depois a url fica `error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/276762/revisions`.

Comment: Confirmo o problema ao tentar acessar aqui no meu dispositivo

Comment: Só esclarecendo, o JNat acrescentou a versão em inglês porque este bug está sendo escalado para os desenvolvedores do site.

Comment: @JNat Não consigo mais reproduzir este bug. Foi consertado? Ou alguma coisa na pergunta relacionada mudou e fez com que deixasse de acontecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto foi reparado no build `2018.2.21.29063`. O código contava com o comentário do histórico de revisões para obter os candidatos para duplicados, anterior e actual, para fazer o diff. Quanto esse comentário foi traduzido, começaram a acontecer os erros.

---

This was fixed in build rev `2018.2.21.29063`. The code relied on revision history comment to get the previous and current duplicate candidate post ids for the diff. As soon as that comment was localized, it started breaking.